# Does $.mobile.loadPage provide a callback function?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

If I wanted to load content that into a jquery mobile page that required its own jquery script, for example a slideshow plug-in, how would I load the slideshow html page "and" the slideshow jquery file into $.mobile.loadPage?  Is there a callback function?

Thanks

Comment: I would look into this: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/pages/page-dynamic.html

Comment: I too would be interested to know if the .loadPage method has a callback. It seems like it must or how else would you be able to cache one page and then continue caching the next ones. Right now if you use data-prefetch on your links it loads them all at once and you have no idea which order they will be inserted into the dom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use "done" after the loadPage. This method will be called once a page has been loaded..

```
 $.mobile.loadPage("page2.html", true).done(function (e, ui, page) {
      //page has been loaded
}).fail(function () {
        alert("sorry, no dice");
    });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no callback function for .loadPage. You can however bind the event pageload to run the required script.

```
 $( document ).bind( "pageload", function( event, data ){
    //your script, and potentially testing you are on a page requiring it
});
```

You can check [Jquery Mobile docs](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html) for the full details on this event. Additionaly, if you were using the much more common .changePage method you could be using the page event "pageshow" or "pagebeforeshow" depending on the kind of script you will be using.